# filter query doesn't work for Platform Encryption

Tags: platform-encryption

i'm trying to perform **Platform Encryption** on contact fields : Phone, Fax, Email

But i'm trying to filter MobilePhone in query

```
SELECT MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE MobilePhone != null
```

getting following error :

> encrypted field 'MobilePhone' cannot be filtered in a query call
>   you can [click here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations.htm&language=fr_1&type=0) for help

Comment: Did you double check that you did not encrypted `MobilePhone`? Also do you have person account enabled?

Comment: MobilePhone is encrypted , thats why the error is and it is nothing to do with person account

Comment: yes i had checked it many time 
i had tried:
sObjectType.Contact.fields.MobilePhone.isEncrypted()
it gives false

Answer (score 1):

> We cannot use long text area field, encrypted data field, or base64-encoded field  in WHERE condition in SOQL or SOSL statement.

Refer [WHERE conditionExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm)